# Compacting a table in a specific server in YugabyteDB instead over the whole cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have a cluster that I run a compaction on a very large table once a week. However the last weekend, one node was unhealthy and the compaction did not run on that node.

Is there any way to run the compaction just on that node?

My understanding is that the compaction through `yb-admin` will run against all nodes that have tablets associated with that table?

Is there a way to run just against one node ?

I also assume there will be less work to do on the nodes that it ran successfully on over the weekend, as most of the data should already have been compacted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [`yb-ts-cli compact_all_tablets`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/admin/yb-ts-cli/#compact-all-tablets%20and) command that compacts all tablets of a yb-tserver.
And there’s also [`yb-ts-cli compact_tablet <tablet_id>`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/admin/yb-ts-cli/#compact-tablet) that compacts a single tablet in a yb-tserver.

> My understanding is that the compaction through `yb-admin` will run
> against all nodes that have tablets associated with that table?

Yes, it will run on all tablets of that table.

> I also assume there will be less work to do on the nodes that it ran
> successfully on over the weekend, as most of the data should already
> have been compacted?

The compaction is forced, therefore it will be redone on the servers where it already ran. It will be less work, but still a lot because it will rewrite the whole tablet into 1 sst file on disk, thus not recommended.

You can use `yb-admin list_tablets` and filter by the ones that have the leader-IP of the node you are interested in to get all the tablets ids that you need to compact for that specific table. And then you run `yb-ts-cli compact_tablet` on each tablet.